# How to stop/disable IPI(inter process interrupts) in linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, irq, softirq

I am trying to disable irq calls from kernel while executing some application, i am calling **local_irq_disable()** before executing my application is that sufficient to disable the IRQ flags.
    Is any other way to disable the IRQ's please suggest me.

Comment: Please explain a bit more what you are trying to accomplish. Normally, one should not mess with inter-processor interrupts. Or, do you mean all interrupts? It is unclear at the moment.

Comment: I am working on jetson Tx2 board, it contains 6 cores of cpu. sometimes i need to shutdown one cpu for other purposes, but in that time IPI calls are automatically triggers and hangs my board. so i am trying to disable IPI calls when i need to shutdown the cpu.                                               
       Is their any way to stop all interrupts? please guide me...

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the CPU for non-kernel work, then the best approach would be to mark it offline (i.e. clear the corresponding bit in cpu_online_mask). Of course, you would have to make sure that there is no pending work that might block other CPUs in the system before you do that…

In other words, go all the way through offlining (hot unplug) without the very last step of actually stopping the CPU. Instead, let it do the special work. When you're done, follow the online steps (hot plug the CPU again).